# Excel VLOOKUP + SUMPRODUCT for multiple

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumproduct

As you can see from my image, I just want to make SUMPRODUCT for each Level 1 (Upper Level) item. And my sample formula is static.

My main aim is to choose column A to find my Level 1 item and make SUMPRODUCT for column C and D which match with each Level 1 item. Also you can see my sample formulas from column H.

Thanks for support.

[My sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvowZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In G2 you could enter `SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$22,$D$2:$D$22,--($A$2:$A$29=F2))` and then copy the formulas down.

Alternatively, you could enter `SUM(($C$2:$C$22)*($D$2:$D$22)*($A$2:$A$22=F2))` if you have Excel Office 365 that supports dynamic arrays.